# Error: 1017 - Compiling a component without entities is not allowed

Tags: compiler-errors, uniface

I got the following compiler error in uniface 9.7:

> error: 1017 - Compiling a component without entities is not allowed.

Which entity should i use? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to implement functionality in Uniface that does not need to interact with any entities, you have two options:

1. Implement your code in a Global Proc instead of in a Component.
2. Implement your code in a Component and paint a "dummy" entity on it. A dummy entity is an entity that does not exist in the Model (and therefore also not in the database)